# Dialog Boxes appearing as stack in android

Tags: android

I am creating 2 dialog boxes at a time, 2nd dialog box appears first(users input goes to it first) then for the 1st dialog box, like a stack. But I want it in reverse order means after giving the input to the first dialog box only second dialog must appear.

simply saying...., I created dialog box with in a for loop if the iteration is 2 then it will create 2 dialog boxes. I want second dialog box must appear after input is given to the first dialog box.

```
    for(int i=0;i<playerCount;i++) {
    AlertDialog.Builder outOfGameBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    outOfGameBuilder.setTitle("Out Of Game");
    //find max count to rejoin

    final int finalMaxCount = maxCount;
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    final TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(i+10);
    message.append(name.getText().toString());
    message.append(" is out of game, Wants to rejoin on ");
    message.append(String.valueOf(maxCount+1));
    outOfGameBuilder.setMessage(message);
    outOfGameBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences(MyPref, MODE_PRIVATE);
        int x = myPref.getInt("i", 0);
        //Log.d("name", name.getText().toString());
        flag[x] = true;
        int maxRow = myPref.getInt("column", 0);
        for(int j=0;j<playerCount;j++) {
        TextView countView = (TextView)findViewById(j+100);
        Log.d("flag:"+j, ":"+flag[j]);
        if(Integer.parseInt(countView.getText().toString()) > finalMaxCount && flag[j]) {
            ed[maxRow][j].setText(String.valueOf(finalMaxCount+1));
            countView.setText(String.valueOf(finalMaxCount+1));
        } else if(flag[j]) {
            ed[maxRow][j].setText(countView.getText().toString());
        }
    }
    });
    outOfGameBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Log.d("name", name.getText().toString());
        arg0.cancel();
    }
    });
    AlertDialog outOfGameDialog = outOfGameBuilder.create();
    outOfGameDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: The last one you call appears on top, so call them in reverse order... Or, better: create the second one when you dismiss the first one.

Comment: I am creating dialog box with in a for loop if the iteration is 2 then it will create 2 dialog boxes. I want second dialog box must appear after input is given to the first dialog box.

Comment: Posting at least the for-loop would really help us to understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: I posted the code please help me....